# CloudML Movielens recommender in production

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-ml

I have worked through the README file of the Movielens CloudML sample: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/movielens

After the pre-processing step I'm left with a bunch of TFRecord files for training evaluation and prediction. I can take the prediction records and run the prediction successfully.

To use this recommender in production, how do I get the prediction record for a specific user? My hope was something along the lines of deploying a streaming Dataflow pipeline that produces the prediction records. How would I go about that?

Comment: The readme mentions "online prediction": a way REST API for serving predictions from your trained model via a JSON request/response. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: It refers to online requests based on pre-processed data (Base64 encoded TFRecords). My question is, how do I get the pre-processed data for a specific user?

Comment: A better example now is TFX Chicago Taxi pipeline, it shows how to read data from BigQuery and then use DataFlow to convert to TFRecords.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/tree/master/tfx/examples/chicago_taxi